# Cannot find header file in CMake project

Tags: cmake

I can't compile this file. I tried to do this in different ways but it never worked. All headers are in the file.

```
silabs_files
    │   bgm220pc22hna.svd
    │   CMakeLists.txt
    │
    ├───autogen
    │       RTE_Components.h
    │       sl_board_default_init.c
    │       sl_component_catalog.h
    │       sl_device_init_clocks.c
    │       sl_event_handler.c
    │       sl_event_handler.h
    │
    ├───config
    │       emlib_core_debug_config.h
    │       pin_config.h
    │       sl_board_control_config.h
    │       sl_device_init_dcdc_config.h
    │       sl_device_init_emu_config.h
    │       sl_device_init_hfxo_config.h
    │       sl_device_init_lfxo_config.h
    │       sl_memory_config.h
    │
    └───gecko_sdk_4.3.1
        ├───hardware
        │   └───board
        │       ├───inc
        │       │       sl_board_control.h
        │       │       sl_board_init.h
        │       │
        │       └───src
        │               sl_board_control_gpio.c
        │               sl_board_init.c
        │
        └───platform
            ├───CMSIS
            │   └───Core
            │       └───Include
            │               cmsis_compiler.h
            │               cmsis_gcc.h
            │               cmsis_version.h
            │               core_cm33.h
            │               mpu_armv8.h
            │               tz_context.h
            │
            ├───common
            │   ├───inc
            │   │       sl_assert.h
            │   │       sl_common.h
            │   │       sl_enum.h
            │   │       sl_status.h
            │   │
            │   ├───src
            │   │       sl_assert.c
            │   │
            │   └───toolchain
            │       ├───inc
            │       │       sl_gcc_preinclude.h
            │       │       sl_memory.h
            │       │       sl_memory_region.h
            │       │
            │       └───src
            │               sl_memory.c
            │
            ├───Device
            │   └───SiliconLabs
            │       └───BGM22
            │           ├───Include
            │           │       bgm220pc22hna.h
            │           │       bgm22_aes.h
            │           │       bgm22_buram.h
            │           │       bgm22_burtc.h
            │           │       bgm22_cmu.h
            │           │       bgm22_cryptoacc.h
            │           │       bgm22_dcdc.h
            │           │       bgm22_devinfo.h
            │           │       bgm22_dma_descriptor.h
            │           │       bgm22_dpll.h
            │           │       bgm22_emu.h
            │           │       bgm22_eusart.h
            │           │       bgm22_fsrco.h
            │           │       bgm22_gpcrc.h
            │           │       bgm22_gpio.h
            │           │       bgm22_gpio_port.h
            │           │       bgm22_hfrco.h
            │           │       bgm22_hfxo.h
            │           │       bgm22_i2c.h
            │           │       bgm22_iadc.h
            │           │       bgm22_icache.h
            │           │       bgm22_ldma.h
            │           │       bgm22_ldmaxbar.h
            │           │       bgm22_ldmaxbar_defines.h
            │           │       bgm22_letimer.h
            │           │       bgm22_lfrco.h
            │           │       bgm22_lfxo.h
            │           │       bgm22_msc.h
            │           │       bgm22_pdm.h
            │           │       bgm22_prs.h
            │           │       bgm22_prs_signals.h
            │           │       bgm22_rtcc.h
            │           │       bgm22_smu.h
            │           │       bgm22_syscfg.h
            │           │       bgm22_timer.h
            │           │       bgm22_ulfrco.h
            │           │       bgm22_usart.h
            │           │       bgm22_wdog.h
            │           │       em_device.h
            │           │       system_bgm22.h
            │           │
            │           └───Source
            │               │   startup_bgm22.c
            │               │   system_bgm22.c
            │               │
            │               └───GCC
            │                       bgm22.ld
            │
            ├───emlib
            │   ├───inc
            │   │       em_assert.h
            │   │       em_bus.h
            │   │       em_chip.h
            │   │       em_cmu.h
            │   │       em_cmu_compat.h
            │   │       em_common.h
            │   │       em_core.h
            │   │       em_core_generic.h
            │   │       em_emu.h
            │   │       em_gpio.h
            │   │       em_ldma.h
            │   │       em_msc.h
            │   │       em_msc_compat.h
            │   │       em_ramfunc.h
            │   │       em_syscfg.h
            │   │       em_system.h
            │   │       em_system_generic.h
            │   │       em_timer.h
            │   │       em_usart.h
            │   │       em_version.h
            │   │       sli_em_cmu.h
            │   │
            │   └───src
            │           em_cmu.c
            │           em_core.c
            │           em_emu.c
            │           em_gpio.c
            │           em_ldma.c
            │           em_msc.c
            │           em_system.c
            │           em_timer.c
            │           em_usart.c
            │
            └───service
                ├───device_init
                │   ├───inc
                │   │       sl_device_init_clocks.h
                │   │       sl_device_init_dcdc.h
                │   │       sl_device_init_emu.h
                │   │       sl_device_init_hfxo.h
                │   │       sl_device_init_lfxo.h
                │   │       sl_device_init_nvic.h
                │   │
                │   └───src
                │           sl_device_init_dcdc_s2.c
                │           sl_device_init_emu_s2.c
                │           sl_device_init_hfxo_s2.c
                │           sl_device_init_lfxo_s2.c
                │           sl_device_init_nvic.c
                │
                └───system
                    ├───inc
                    │       sl_system_init.h
                    │       sl_system_process_action.h
                    │
                    └───src
                            sl_system_init.c
                            sl_system_process_action.c
```

My `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(silabs_files)

set(SILABS_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES
    autogen
    config
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/hardware/board/inc
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/CMSIS/Core/Include
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/common/inc
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/common/toolchain/inc
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/Device/SiliconLabs/BGM22/Include
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/emlib/inc
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/service/device_init/inc
    gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/service/system/inc)

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCES
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.c)

add_library(${PROJECT_NAME}
            STATIC
            ${SOURCES})

target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} 
                           PUBLIC
                           SILABS_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES)
```

I get this error:

```
[main] Configuring project: silabs_files 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\cmake-3.27.5-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\tools\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\tools\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -SC:/Users/Mehatronika/Desktop/Cmake11/silabs_files -Bc:/Users/Mehatronika/Desktop/Cmake11/silabs_files/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
[main] Configuring project: silabs_files 
[cmake] Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
[cmake] -- The C compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
[cmake] -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 13.1.0
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting C compile features - done
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
[cmake] -- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/tools/msys64/ucrt64/bin/g++.exe - skipped
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features
[cmake] -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
[cmake] -- Configuring done (1.9s)
[cmake] -- Generating done (0.0s)
[cmake] -- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Mehatronika/Desktop/Cmake11/silabs_files/build
[build] Starting build
[proc] Executing command: chcp
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\cmake-3.27.5-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/Mehatronika/Desktop/Cmake11/silabs_files/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 --
[build] [  3%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/autogen/sl_board_default_init.c.obj
[build] [  7%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/autogen/sl_device_init_clocks.c.obj
[build] [ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/CMakeFiles/3.27.5/CompilerIdC/CMakeCCompilerId.c.obj
[build] [ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/autogen/sl_event_handler.c.obj
[build] [ 18%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/hardware/board/src/sl_board_init.c.obj
[build] [ 22%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/hardware/board/src/sl_board_control_gpio.c.obj
[build] [ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/Device/SiliconLabs/BGM22/Source/startup_bgm22.c.obj
[build] [ 29%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/common/src/sl_assert.c.obj
[build] [ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/Device/SiliconLabs/BGM22/Source/system_bgm22.c.obj
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\autogen\sl_device_init_clocks.c:30:10: fatal error: sl_device_init_clocks.h: No such file or directory
[build]    30 | #include "sl_device_init_clocks.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] [ 37%] Building C object CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/common/toolchain/src/sl_memory.c.obj
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\gecko_sdk_4.3.1\hardware\board\src\sl_board_init.c:30:10: fatal error: sl_board_control.h: No such file or directory
[build]    30 | #include "sl_board_control.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:91: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/autogen/sl_device_init_clocks.c.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:151: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/hardware/board/src/sl_board_init.c.obj] Error 1
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\gecko_sdk_4.3.1\platform\common\src\sl_assert.c:31:10: fatal error: sl_assert.h: No such file or directory
[build]    31 | #include "sl_assert.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\gecko_sdk_4.3.1\platform\Device\SiliconLabs\BGM22\Source\startup_bgm22.c:38:10: fatal error: em_device.h: No such file or directory
[build]    38 | #include "em_device.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\gecko_sdk_4.3.1\platform\Device\SiliconLabs\BGM22\Source\system_bgm22.c:32:10: fatal error: em_device.h: No such file or directory
[build]    32 | #include "em_device.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:196: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/common/src/sl_assert.c.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:181: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/Device/SiliconLabs/BGM22/Source/system_bgm22.c.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:166: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/Device/SiliconLabs/BGM22/Source/startup_bgm22.c.obj] Error 1
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\autogen\sl_event_handler.c:3:10: fatal error: em_chip.h: No such file or directory
[build]     3 | #include "em_chip.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\gecko_sdk_4.3.1\hardware\board\src\sl_board_control_gpio.c:30:10: fatal error: sl_board_control.h: No such file or directory
[build]    30 | #include "sl_board_control.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:136: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/hardware/board/src/sl_board_control_gpio.c.obj] Error 1
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\autogen\sl_board_default_init.c:30:10: fatal error: sl_board_control.h: No such file or directory
[build]    30 | #include "sl_board_control.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:106: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/autogen/sl_event_handler.c.obj] Error 1
[build] C:\Users\Mehatronika\Desktop\Cmake11\silabs_files\gecko_sdk_4.3.1\platform\common\toolchain\src\sl_memory.c:31:10: fatal error: em_device.h: No such file or directory
[build]    31 | #include "em_device.h"
[build]       |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] compilation terminated.
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:211: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/gecko_sdk_4.3.1/platform/common/toolchain/src/sl_memory.c.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\silabs_files.dir\build.make:76: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/autogen/sl_board_default_init.c.obj] Error 1
[build] mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:82: CMakeFiles/silabs_files.dir/all] Error 2
[build] mingw32-make: *** [Makefile:90: all] Error 2
[proc] The command: "C:\Program Files (x86)\cmake-3.27.5-windows-x86_64\bin\cmake.EXE" --build c:/Users/Mehatronika/Desktop/Cmake11/silabs_files/build --config Debug --target all -j 10 -- exited with code: 2
[driver] Build completed: 00:00:00.450
[build] Build finished with exit code 2
```

Comment: In your `CMakeLists.txt` set variable [CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html) to ON. That way every time a compiler will be launched during the build, CMake (MinGW) will print exact parameters passed to the compiler. Check that among those parameters exits the `-I` one, which adds the include directory which contains the missed headers.